# All files in public_html, Cannot launch WordPress site via wp-admin

Tags: permalinks, wp-admin, uploads, htaccess, configuration

my registered URL is
`casualtyclaimscontainment.com`
I developed the site on AMPPS using the URL `kriswebpg.test`

I uploaded site to `https://dallas124.mysitehosted.com`
I have tried everything in my knowledge to launch wordpress after successfully installing WordPress from cPanel with SOFTACULOUS installer.
I get the following error:

> This site can’t be reached 
>   casualtyclaimscontainment.com 
>   refused to connect.
>   ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

or with incognito page get the error msg: 404 Not Found 
`www.casualtyclaimscontainment.com/wp-admin` (port 443)

I have explored all the internet solutions still no joy.
under directory public_html the `.htaccess` file is shown below.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: There are many inconsistencies here... ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED is most likely a DNS error, not related to WordPress. If I try to access `casualtyclaimscontainment.com` I get a redirect loop? You mention a 404 response? I'm also getting an "intermittent"(?) SSL cert warning when accessing your domain via port 443? You say you uploaded the site to `https://dallas124.mysitehosted.com` - so how does your registered domain relate to this? Can you serve a simple HTML page from your domain?

Comment: I disabled all SSL to try and simply bring up page. no joy
I checked DNS:  A, CNAME, MX,Records reflect casualtyclaimscontainment.com. 
I cannot try a page as I cannot get Wordpress to launch.
I would have simply retyped the page if I could get access

Comment: Can you share your folder structure?

Comment: It sounds like you're saying you set up WordPress as a local site, then uploaded the files (and probably the database) to your actual host. If that's correct, you skipped a step - updating all the URLs. You'll need to use a database migration plugin that will handle the URL changes from your local URL to the actual end domain - there are a couple of settings in the options table but also URLs throughout the database that are often serialized and get corrupted if you try to just search and replace manually.

Comment: Folder structure
<public_html>
  cgi-bin
  kris

  <<wp>>
    wp-admin
    wp-content
    wp-includes

  <<wp-admin>>
    css
    images
    includes
    js
    maint
    network
    user

  <<wp-content>>
    ai1wm-backups
    aiowps_backups
    mu-plugins
    plugins
    themes
    upgrade
    uploads
    wflogs

  <<wp-includes>>
    blocks
    certificates
    css
    customize
    fonts
    ID3
    images
    IXR
    js
    pomo
    random_compat
    Requests
    rest-api
    SimplePie
    sodium_compat
    Text
    theme-compat
    widgets

Comment: Yes I think that is my mistake, my URLs have not been edited properly...I used all-in-one-wp-migration.6.96
I downloaded Search-Replace-DB-3-1-0-emaildownloads
database search and replace scripts, it lacked documentation on how to run script safetly.

Comment: fixed the problem by editing the host file to remove URL from the localhost